# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I am new to Angular. I am using Angular 7 and doing a  simple routing.
After Login page, I want to display a home page. Login is a part of `app-root` component and in home page I am showing **header** and **sidenav** but I am not able to route to home page.

**app-routimg.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'
},
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashBoardModule',

}
];
  @NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
   // providers: [AuthGuard]
}
```

**dashboard-routing.modul.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashBoardComponent ,
    children: [
         {
             path: '',
            redirectTo: 'home'
        },
        {
            path: 'home',
            loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
        },

    ]
}
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
```

**login.component.ts**

```
onSubmit() {

       this._router.navigate(['/home']);
      }
}
```

[image]

> core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match
>   any routes. URL Segment: 'home' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL
>   Segment: 'home'

Comment: Please show your routuing configuration

Comment: did u placed <router-outlet></router-outlet>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be like this in your dashboard-routing-module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: DashBoardComponent,
  children: [
   {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'home',
      pathMatch: 'prefix'
   },
   {
      path: 'home',
      component: HomeComponent
   }
 ]
}];
```

Comment: I'm seeing routes in the answer, but the error mentioned "segments". What is a segment vs a route?

Answer (score 1):

you must use this code :

```
this._router.navigate(['/dashboard/home']);
```

if it doesn't work, in "dashboard-routing.modul.ts" file use path: ' ', instead of
 path: 'dashboard',.

Comment: your dashboard routeModule must be like this:

const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      component : DashBoardComponent,
        children : [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'prefix' },
            {
              path: 'home',
              component: HomeComponent,
          
            },
        ],
    }
];

Comment: copy and paste my code in your dashboard routeModule

Comment: Sorry it got fixed.. Its seems in the header page also I had to use '/dashboard/home'..

Comment: Can you please look in to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56089743/cannot-read-property-isxxxxx-of-undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193184/discussion-between-subham-and-mohammadreza-imani).