# Cannot read property 'isXXXXX' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I am trying to use a shared service on one of my components. When I am using with app root component then it is working fine. When I am trying to use on another module/dashboard then I am getting an error.

**[image: shared/authorize.service.ts]**

**shared/authorize.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthorizationService {
  isDoingSomething() {
    return "Some Boolean value";
  }
}
```

**dashboard/header/header.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent {
 constructor(private _auth: AuthorizeService,
          private _router: Router) { }
}
```

**dashboard/header/header.component.html**

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" role="heading">
  <div fxFlex fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="flex-end">
    <ul fxLayout fxLayoutGap="10px" class="navigation-items">
      <li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
        <a routerLink="/home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li routerLinkActive="active">
        <a *ngIf="_auth.isDoingSomething()" routerLink="/docall">Rest Call</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</mat-toolbar>
```

> ```
> **HeaderComponent.html:6 ERROR TypeError:** Cannot read property 'isDoingSomething' of undefined
>      at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (HeaderComponent.html:6)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23911)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23307)
> ```

Comment: Try this for your service injector `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using lazy-loading in your app if it is, you must create a shared module and add your service in its providers, then import it in each module you want to use it.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [],
  exports:[],
  providers: [
     YourService
  ]
})

 export class SharedModule {
}
```